# C# Selenium XPATH Click Input based on text from Span

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click an input button whose main identifiers are dynamically created.  Therefore I'm trying to click it based on the span information after it.

```
<span id="DYNAMIC" class="a-button a-button-primary pmts-button-input apx-compact-continue-action pmts-portal-component pmts-portal-components-DYNAMIC primary-action-button">
<span class="a-button-inner">
    <input data-pmts-component-id="DYNAMIC" class="a-button-input a-button-text" type="submit" aria-labelledby="DYNAMIC">
        <span id="DYNAMIC" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
            <span>Use this payment method</span>
        </span>
</span>
```

I've put in the word DYNAMIC where the IDs are dynamically created rather than putting in the value.  Below is what I think was my best version of the many things I tried but I've still not been able to accomplish the task.

```
var btnPaymentMethod = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[normalize-space(.//span)='Use this payment method']"));
btnPaymentMethod.Click();
```

Comment: Seems your input contains 2 child spans

What about driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[normalize-space(.//span//span)='Use this payment method']"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To click on input button with reference to span tag.Use below xpath.

```
//span[text()='Use this payment method']/preceding::input[1]
```

Try the below code.

```
var btnPaymentMethod = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Use this payment method']/preceding::input[1]"));
btnPaymentMethod.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath,

```
var btnPaymentMethod = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@span,'Use this payment method')]"));
btnPaymentMethod.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Use this payment method**, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("span.a-button-inner span.a-button-text>span"))).Click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[@class='a-button-text']/span[text()='Use this payment method']"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath's will also locate the input element for you:

```
"//span[text() = 'Use this payment method']/../parent::span/input"

"//span[contains(text(), 'Use this payment method')]/../parent::span/input"
```